# What is the proper and non-blocking way to run a setInterval function in a route of an express application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I need to repeatedly call a function to update my database collections in one of my routes in my express application. I want to understand the right way to go about it. I am making use of setInterval() at present.

The function I am trying to invoke is asynchronous in nature. I have tried the following implementation in one of the routes I have.

```
var express = require('express');
var sampleRouter = express.Router();

....

const callFunction = () => {
  // async function being called here
};

setInterval(callFunction, 30000);
```

Currently, the repeated function call is not running as per the expected time intervals. I believe it is getting blocked in some way.

Comment: It's almost never the right design to start a `setInterval()` in a route handler.  That's because you would be starting a new timer for every single time that route handler was hit by every single client that hits it and (usually), never stopping it. There are better ways to solve your problem.  But, for us to help you with the REAL problem, you'd have to describe the actual problem in more detail. What you have here is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you asked about a possible solution rather than asking about the original problem.

Comment: Basically I want to be able to run a function repeatedly anywhere in the application. How do I go about it? You can find my current implementation here. https://github.com/tarique93102/nicole/blob/master/server/routes/products.js
However, as pointed out in the question the interval is not triggered as expected.

Comment: Well, `setInterval()` when used properly calls a function on a recurring timer.  That's how you do it in node.js.  node.js is single threaded and `setInterval()` is not pre-emptive so the interval time is approximate.  When it is time for the timer to fire, it inserts an event into the event queue and when the current event is finished and node.js goes to fetch the next event from the event queue, then your timer callback can run.

Comment: What's the specific problem with your `setInterval()` [here](https://github.com/tarique93102/nicole/blob/master/server/routes/products.js#L142).  With that code, your timer should run every 5 minutes unless your node.js server is bogged down running some long running synchronous, blocking operation in which case the timer callback will run when that finishes.

Comment: Given the implementation. What do you suggest?

Comment: Suggest for what?  I see no problem with the code by just looking at it - that's how you call a function on a recurring interval.  Until you describe a more specific problem in detail and with some info from debugging the problem, I don't see how anyone else can help you further.  That function should run about every 5 minutes.  Perhaps you have an error inside your callback that prevents it from completing.  I have no idea on that as I can't run it or debug it.  That's what  you have to do or give us a lot more specific info you've gathered from debugging the problem yourself.

Comment: I meant suggestion for using the setInterval() in the router file the way I had used. If that is fine. I will continue to monitor the call further.

Comment: Conceptually, that is fine.  I can't speak to how much you're loading your database when you're doing that, but conceptually, that's how you execute a function every 5 minutes in a node.js server, assuming that module gets loaded and properly initialized.

Comment: Cool. That works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceptually, what you're doing with the `setInterval()` to set to run every 5 minutes [here](https://github.com/tarique93102/nicole/blob/master/server/routes/products.js#L142) is fine. That's how you schedule a function to be called on a recurring basis in node.js.

I can't speak to how much you're loading your database when you're doing that, but conceptually, that's how you execute a function every 5 minutes in a node.js server, assuming that module gets loaded and properly initialized.

Keep in mind that node.js runs your Javascript single threaded and all timers in Javascript are non-preemptive so all timers in node.js are approximate.  When the timer fires, they will insert an event in the event queue and as soon as node.js finishes what it was doing and fetches the next event and the timer event has bubbled to the top of the queue, then your timer callback will get called.  Unless your server is off doing some long-running, blocking, synchronous task (which node.js servers shouldn't be doing any way), this model of timer is typically perfectly fine for most things.  And, in your case of some database housekeeping, it should work just fine.